# Differential equation where Picard-Lindelöf can not be applied

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, proof-verification

My question is the following :

> Let $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ be  continuous function and let $u:[a,b]\to\mathbb{R}$ be a $C^1$ function such that
>   $$\forall t\in[a,b],u'(t)=f(u(t))\text{ and }u(a)=u(b)=k\in\mathbb{R}.$$
>   Show that $u$ must be constant.

**What I have done :**

We show that $\max u=k$ (and a similar proof would show that $\min u=k).$ Let's suppose that $\max u=M>k.$ We note $c\in]a,b[$ a point such that $u(c)=M.$ The mean value theorem give us a point $d^+\in ]a,c[$ such that $$u'(d^+)=\frac{u(c)-u(a)}{c-a}=\frac{M-k}{c-a}>0.$$ We note $m=u(d^+).$ The intermediate value theorem tell us that it exists a point $d^-\in]c,b[$ such that $u(d^-)=m$ : we can suppose that $u'(d^-)\leq 0,$ else we would have that, for all $x\in]c,b[$ such that $u(x)=m,$ $u'(x)>0.$ It would be true in particular for $x_{max},$ the biggest $x$ such that $u(x)=m$ : as $u'$ is continuous, it would give us $u'(t)>0$ for $t$ in a neighborhood $[x_l,x_r]$ of $x_{max},$ which would implies $$\int_{x_{max}}^{x_r}u'(t)\,dt=u(x_r)-u(x_{max})>0,$$ and so $u(x_r)>m.$ By continuity of $u$, it is impossible (mean value theorem applied to $u$ on $[x_r,b]$ : there would be no point in this interval which would reach $m$, while $u(x_r)>m$ and $u(c)<m$). Finally, we have two points $d^+$ and $d^-$ such that 
$$0<u'(d^+)=f(u(d^+))=f(m)=f(u(d^-))=u'(d^-)\leq 0,$$ 
and so a contradiction. We get our result.

**My question :**
Is my proof correct ? And if yes, is there a faster way to prove that result ? Thank you for your time !

**Edit :** After some discussion with Jonas, we agree that this proof is correct and are talking about details in this specific way of proving that result. I am starting a bounty to answer the second part of my question : does someone see a faster way to solve it ? Thank you for your attention.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using integration by substitution it is seen that:
$$
 0 = \int_{k}^{k} f(x) dx = \int_{u(a)}^{u(b)} f(x) dx = \int_{a}^{b} f(u(t)) u'(t) dt = \int_{a}^{b} ( u'(t) )^{2} dt. 
$$

Thus $u'(t) = 0$ on $[a,b]$, so $u$ is constant.

Comment: Wonderful !!  Thank you very much !

Answer (score 0):

Your proof seems correct to me. 
Let me suggest a simpler argument (somewhat based on yours):

Since $f$ is only continuous the solutions may not be unique but still, in order to start at $k=u(a)$ and reach some bigger value at a later time necessarily $u'(t)>0$ for some $t\in(a,b)$. But since $u(b)=k$ the solution needs to return and pass in particular through $u(t)$ but in the opposite direction, which requires that $u'(t)\le0$ (it could be zero because of the possible nonuniqueness). This contradiction show the solution cannot reach a higher value. Similar arguments apply to the other direction.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I agree that the argument is shorter, but I try to find a really formal proof : so when we say "in the opposite direction, which requires that...",  I agree that it is a totally right argument, but I want to show every point really clearly. An other point : when you say "it could be zero because of the possible nonuniqueness", I think it comes from the fact that $u$ can cross the level line as $x\mapsto x^3$ cross $y=0,$ i.e. with a nul-derivative ?

Comment: What you call "formal" some call "unreadable". :) But notice that you don't need the intermediate value theorem, integrals, etc, for a "formal" proof. No, not like $x^3$, either you assume more than continuity for $f$ or you really will have in general nonunique solutions (so either you consider a particular $u$ as in your argument, or you consider all solutions at the same time, as in my argument, in which case nonuniqueness is a crucial point).

Comment: I agree that at a certain level, these arguments have not to be developed, but one should do some proofs as this one before to allow himself just giving the ideas ;) And, about this problem of "$\leq$", here note that I study a fixed solution, so I don't care about other potential solutions : the only fact I wanted to precise is that the point where $u$ will reach the value $m$ while "decreasing", then at that point the derivative could be equal to $0$ as in the cube example !

Comment: So I think I did not really understand what you want to mean with "nonuniqueness" here ?

Comment: Perhaps nonuniqueness of the point $x$ where $u(x)=m$ ?

Comment: No problem, see you later and thank you for your time and attention !

Comment: Please just tell me the next time that you have not the time to follow your help, instead of erasing your comment...

Comment: I erased my comment because I was going to add details to my answer, as promised, but could not do it immediately. Unfortunately I can do it only when I can do it, sorry for that, and to give an explicit example required sitting down and compute. Never mind, I will leave all as it is, after all all I have already answered, crystal clear. Next time try to be more appreciative.

Comment: I have only remarked that you have answered a lot of other questions while I was standing for the following of our discussion. However, my comment could have been to fast and inappropriate, and so I apologize about it. Hope we will finish to discuss about that topic !

Comment: True, but many are much more automatic than yours (which incidentally I appreciated much more than others). I was tempted to only write "Draw the phase portrait", but presumably it would be considered almost  offensive, since it would very much nonformal. :)

Comment: I agree that all the proof is in these some words, and that all the difficulty is to translate it as an homework (perhaps I should have precise that it was the goal of this verification before all !). For information, the teacher has said that the proof was correct, but asked : how would you precise that you can consider $x_{max}$ ? I answered : $x_{max}=\sup\{x\in[c,b]\, ;\,u(x)=m\}=u^{-1}|_{[c,b]}(\{m\}),$ so a closed of a compact - and so a compact : it contains its $\sup$... Just to show the degree of details he was looking for ^^'